# Could not find a type identifier for the class : class java.lang.Short

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I have an issue with serialization of `Byte` and `Short` types using `GraphSONMapper`

I am using default configuration of JanusGraph started by

```
docker run -it -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph
```

and sample database `The Graph of the Gods`

---

Here is example with `Short`:

```
query = g.V().hasLabel('vertex_data_types').limit(1000).valueMap(true).toList();

mapper = GraphSONMapper.build().version(GraphSONVersion.V3_0).addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.instance()).create().createMapper();

mapper.writeValueAsString(query)
```

Full response:

```
gremlin> query = g.V().hasLabel('vertex_data_types').limit(1000).valueMap(true).toList();
==>{id=12520, label=vertex_data_types, test_short=[2], test_int=[5]}
gremlin> mapper = GraphSONMapper.build().version(GraphSONVersion.V3_0).addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.instance()).create().createMapper();
==>org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@789b15a4
gremlin> mapper.writeValueAsString(query)
Could not find a type identifier for the class : class java.lang.Short. Make sure the value to serialize has a type identifier registered for its class.
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]Y
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a type identifier for the class : class java.lang.Short. Make sure the value to serialize has a type identifier registered for its class.
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeIdResolver.idFromValueAndType(GraphSONTypeIdResolver.java:82)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeSerializerV3d0.writeTypePrefix(GraphSONTypeSerializerV3d0.java:83)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdScalarSerializer.serializeWithType(StdScalarSerializer.java:44)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2656)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:381)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.JavaUtilSerializersV3d0$ListJacksonSerializer.serialize(JavaUtilSerializersV3d0.java:127)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.JavaUtilSerializersV3d0$ListJacksonSerializer.serializeWithType(JavaUtilSerializersV3d0.java:135)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.JavaUtilSerializersV3d0$ListJacksonSerializer.serializeWithType(JavaUtilSerializersV3d0.java:118)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2656)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:381)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.JavaUtilSerializersV3d0$MapJacksonSerializer.serialize(JavaUtilSerializersV3d0.java:59)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.JavaUtilSerializersV3d0$MapJacksonSerializer.serializeWithType(JavaUtilSerializersV3d0.java:67)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.JavaUtilSerializersV3d0$MapJacksonSerializer.serializeWithType(JavaUtilSerializersV3d0.java:49)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2656)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.writeObject(GeneratorBase.java:381)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.JavaUtilSerializersV3d0$ListJacksonSerializer.serialize(JavaUtilSerializersV3d0.java:127)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.JavaUtilSerializersV3d0$ListJacksonSerializer.serializeWithType(JavaUtilSerializersV3d0.java:135)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.JavaUtilSerializersV3d0$ListJacksonSerializer.serializeWithType(JavaUtilSerializersV3d0.java:118)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3906)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3220)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper$writeValueAsString.call(Unknown Source)
        at Script64.run(Script64.groovy:1)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:674)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:376)
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:267)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
gremlin>
```

```
gremlin> g.getGraph().openManagement().printPropertyKeys()
==>------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Property Key Name              | Cardinality | Data Type                                          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test_short                     | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Short                              |
test_int                       | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
name                           | SINGLE      | class java.lang.String                             |
age                            | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
time                           | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
reason                         | SINGLE      | class java.lang.String                             |
place                          | SINGLE      | class org.janusgraph.core.attribute.Geoshape       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why `GraphSONMapper` not able to serialize `Byte` and `Short` data types? Does it needs any additional configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphSON can serialiaze short and byte types. I asked this question in [discussion tab on GitHub](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/discussions/2596) and [received this link](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.11/dev/io/#_extended_2)

Here is how my code looks now:

```
GraphSONMapper.
            build().
            typeInfo(org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.TypeInfo.PARTIAL_TYPES).
            addCustomModule(org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONXModuleV2d0.build().create(false)).
            version(GraphSONVersion.V3_0).
            addRegistry(JanusGraphIoRegistry.instance()).
            create().
            createMapper().
            writeValueAsString(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, maybe it was an oversight, but [GraphSON](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.10/dev/io/#graphson-3d0) has never supported `short` or `byte` serialization. If you need such support you should switch to [GraphBinary](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.10/dev/io/#graphbinary). On older versions, if you were using the JVM, you might have also considered [Gryo](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.10/dev/io/#gryo), but it is now deprecated in favor of GraphBinary.

If you must use GraphSON, it would mean writing your own custom serializers (usually as part of an `IoRegistry` implementation) for those types and then configuring them into the server and your client. You can get a rough idea of how to do this by examining the [JanusGraphIoRegistry](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.5.3/janusgraph-driver/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/tinkerpop/JanusGraphIoRegistry.java) or perhaps a more simple implementation of the [TinkerIoRegistry](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.10/tinkergraph-gremlin/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/tinkergraph/structure/TinkerIoRegistryV3d0.java).